# Cannot resolve thisJointPoint.getArgs()

Tags: intellij-idea, aspectj

I have this AspectJ code running in my project, but the IDE (IntelliJ) tells that it "Cannot resolve getArgs()" in the `thisJoinPoint`. Why this error is happening? Should I import any aspectJ library to my project?

```
package org.apache.hadoop.mapred.aspects;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.mylib;

public aspect MapReduceCalls {
    Mylib mylib;

    before(): execution(* run(..)) {
        mylib = new Mylib();
    }

    before(): call(* org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.cleanup(..)) || call(* org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.cleanup(..)) {
        Object obj = thisJoinPoint.getArgs()[0];

        try {
            mylib.cleanup(obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need the AspectJ runtime library *aspectjrt.jar* on your class path.